# Which encoding to use for reading Italian text in Python?

Tags: python, visual-studio-2010, encoding

I'm using Python Tools for Visual Studio and reading some files written in Italian. Tried iso-8859-1, iso-8859-2, utf-8, utf-8-sig. Notepad++ opens the file as UTF-8 without BOM.

```
content = fp.read()
words = content.decode("utf-8-sig").lower().split()
for w in words:
    p=''
    cur.execute('SELECT word FROM  multiwordnet.italian_lemma l, multiwordnet.italian_synset s where l.id = s.id and l.lemma="%s"' % w)
```

The string that results in a crash is `C'è`. (Getting read as `"c\'\xe3\xa8"`)

Using chardet does not help

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Tathagata\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\PythonApplicati
on4\PythonApplication4\PythonApplication4.py", line 344, in <module>
createSynsetDict()
File "C:\Users\Tathagata\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\PythonApplicati
on4\PythonApplication4\PythonApplication4.py", line 294, in createSynsetDict
cur.execute('SELECT word FROM  multiwordnet.italian_lemma l, multiwordnet.it
alian_synset s where l.id = s.id and l.lemma="%s"' % w)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 117, in execute
self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 187, in defa
ulterrorhandler
raise Error(errorclass, errorvalue)
Error: (<type 'exceptions.UnicodeEncodeError'>, UnicodeEncodeError('ascii', u's\
x00\x00\x00\x03SELECT word FROM  multiwordnet.italian_lemma l, multiwordnet.ital 
ian_synset s where l.id = s.id and l.lemma="c\'\xe3\xa8"', 116, 118, 'ordinal no
t in range(128)'))
```

Comment: [How Do I Stop The Pain?](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html)

Comment: Which DB-API binding are you using? (That is, which database driver?)

Comment: ...actually, more to the point, what is the value of the `paramstyle` global in your database library's module? (If you don't know, just identify the module, and we can look it up).

Comment: See the full code and more of @CharlesDuffy -s comments on the gist(https://gist.github.com/tathagata/5320310)

Answer (score 1):

Presuming that your database's style of bind variables is `format`...

```
content = fp.read()
words = content.decode("utf-8-sig").lower().split()
for w in words:
    p=''
    cur.execute('SELECT word FROM ' +
                'multiwordnet.italian_lemma l, ' +
                'multiwordnet.italian_synset s ' +
                'where l.id = s.id and l.lemma=%s', w)
```

Note that we aren't using a `%` operator between the SQL string and the variable being passed in, and we aren't putting inner quotes around the `%s`; rather, the `%s` is a placeholder to identify where in the SQL the word should be substituted, and we're passing the value to be substituted for that placeholder as a separate argument. Following this practice not only prevents you from needing deal with encoding issues (if your argument is passed as a Python Unicode string, the database bindings are responsible for taking it from there), but also prevents [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) security vulnerabilities.

Other database libraries for Python may use different placeholder styles; read the documentation or check the module-level `paramstyle` constant for yours. (for `qmark` your placeholder should be `?`; for `numeric` it should be colon-prefixed numbers (`:1` for the first parameter, `:2` for the second, etc)

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. I'm using PyMySQL[https://github.com/petehunt/PyMySQL/] which has `paramstyle=format` which is why the code kept working till it reaches any word with funny characters. If I use `?` for as you suggested it throws a KeyError[http://pastebin.com/V7T6xbkY] even for words that were readable with `%s`.

Comment: @Tathagata Yes -- with `format`, you should use `%s` instead of `?`, but still use a comma instead of a `%` operator. I'm updating the answer appropriately.

Comment: @Tathagata ...by the way, in the future, please avoid pastebin.com links; it's full of flashy animated ads for anyone not using Adblock.

Comment: on pastebin: Wow, I had no idea. Its such a different view of the Internet that you get without an adblock!

Comment: While your answer was insightful, it didn't solve the problem. And I'm getting around it by throwing it into a try catch with a pass. I really appreciate the time and effort you put in and thanks once again!

Comment: @Tathagata Going back to your old code and doing the try/catch thing leaves you open to security bugs; it's REALLY better not to do that. Could you show the new code you tried that failed and the new exception? (The old exception came from the `%` operator, so the new failure would be something different).

Comment: Just letting you know, there is no need to be concerned about security. As I'm the sole user, and I don't plan to be under the influnece of any intoxicating beverage any time soon, so self-destruction by sql-injecting my own code is out of the picture. J